# Django Password Reset Email - Custom User model with Mobile No as Username

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

I have a custom `User` model where Mobile number is the `USERNAME`. I have a `UserProfile` Model that is One-To-One related to the `User`. This UserProfile model also has the `email` field. I want to create a password reset via email flow in my project.

I did not find the documentation(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) for `password_reset` eloquent enough to explain how it would fit in the whole flow. Is there some example/tutorial that can explain better? Is there any other way hot it could be done?

EDIT : The links by Glyn and Muhammad don't seem to work for the kind of `User` and `UserProfile` model relationship I have.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the password reset form and customise as needed. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm

There are also a number of packages that work well for example, https://github.com/brutasse/django-password-reset